# How to use VBA to search for a list of words and phrases in a Word document and highlight them?

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight

So I have a large list of words and phrases that should not be used in a word document. I would like to write a macro to search a document for these words and phrases and highlight them.

So far I have found and edited some code to search for specific words and it'll highlight those:

```
Sub Find_Liability_Words()
'
' Find_Liability_Words Macro
'
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
Dim StrFnd As String, i As Long, StrRpt As String

' Words to search for
StrFnd = "actually,administer,advise,affirmative,all,always"

With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.Highlight = True
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Format = True
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchAllWordForms = True
  For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFnd, ","))
    .Text = Split(StrFnd, ",")(i)
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    If .Found = True Then StrRpt = StrRpt & vbCr & Split(StrFnd, ",")(i)
  Next
End With
If StrRpt = "" Then
  MsgBox "None of the terms were found.", vbOKOnly
Else
  MsgBox "The following terms were found:" & StrRpt, vbInformation
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Now the issue is that this can only do words and shows an error when trying to find to words together (such as "adequate number"). I am wondering how to make it search for a phrase as well.

In addition to this, the list of words and phrases I'd like to search for is long and could change so editing the code for this could be tedious. Is it possible to have this code refer to a text file or an excel sheet in order to find it's words and phrases?

Thank you so much for any help!!

Comment: What's the text of the error you get?

Comment: @TimWilliams, The error is "Runt0time error '5610': The Find What text for a Find All Word Forms search can only contain alphabetic letter.
My guess is that it is recognizing a space as non-alphabetic but I don't know how to resolve.

Comment: I guess Word can't do query expansion for multi-word queries?  You may stuck with that.

Comment: Do you *need* to search "all word forms"? This can only work with a word, not a phrase. You could have your code "branch" depending on whether a search term contains more than one word (a space), setting `MatchAllWordForms` to False when that's the case.